# Why Uitextfield return null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, uitextfield

I selected date from picker in textfield and click send button for soap call.But textfield return null.The message of soap is

< date1 >null< date1 >
< date2 >null< date2 >

.h

```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *Date1;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *Date2;
```

.m

```
    @synthesize Date1,Date2;


-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {

[Date1 resignFirstResponder];
[Date2 resignFirstResponder];


 }


 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
Date1 = textField;
Date2 = textField;


[self addInputViewToTextField:textField];
[self addInputViewToTextField:textField];

 }
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

Date1 = nil;
Date2 = nil;

 }

- (void)viewDidUnload {

[self setDate1:nil];
[self setDate2:nil];

[super viewDidUnload];

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your `textFieldDidEndEditing` you are making the UITextFiled's nil. This method is called whenever a UITextField resigns as first responder.(and if the delegate is set to your class)

Answer (score 2):

YOu have used

```
Date1 = nil;
Date2 = nil;

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
```

thats what is making it empty

Answer (score 2):

1)Set the delegate For the both textField

2)In - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField.

you can check weather textFiled object is date1 or date2.
  Write the code for what you want do with the text.